# How to get live data from excel to a webpage?

Tags: html, excel, web

I have an excel which gets live data from a thrid party. I want to display that live data from excel in a webpage. Can someone guide on how to do it?

Any inputs appreciate

Thank you

Comment: You cannot run an excel file like it's done in ExcelUI application. You can read cell values from the excel file(without excel.exe) but you only see values at the time of saving a file.

Comment: You can hack this by keeping Windows box running excel and file be opened in it, then some timer mechanism to ask xls macros to push active values to a database or create json file on web server. / maybe it works but not very 24h7d auto-service

Comment: Third is Microsoft SharePoint server and web excel.

Answer (score 0):

Your server will need to make a query of the same source. The following is one of dozens of ways to do this.

Set up a cron job to to the following:
1:Use curl to pull the data.
2:Use an awk program to reformat the data to a data file as a table with html table markup.
3:Concatenate a header file, your data file, and a trailer file to make a valid html file that you want.
4:Store that file on the web server.

If you want to do live updates rather than have the user reload the file you either have to push the data, or write JavaScript to reload the webpage element at intervals.

This is an excellent project. Learn this and you’ll have a big step up in your web building skills.